# Unknown symbols in vim near filename and filetype

Tags: plugin-airline

## Description

I have a problem with weird unknown symbols in the fileformat placement and encoding sections.

## Environment

- vim: 7.4.1689
- vim-airline: 0.9
- OS: Ubuntu 16.04
- Reproduced with a minimal vimrc: yes
- vimrc config [link](http://freetexthost.com/iplxmcqls4)
- Tested on terminals: xfce4-terminal, pantheon-terminal, gnome-terminal, xterm
- $TERM variable: xterm-256color
- color configuration (:set t_Co?): t_Co=256
- am i using Neovim: No
- does it happen in Vim: Yes

Here is screenshot without `let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1` in `.vimrc` , i've commented it.
[image]

**I want to NOTICE, these symbols are not undisplayed arrow symbols, because i see it in normal, font-enabled mode too**
[image]

I have tried to edit
`let g:airline_section_y (fileencoding, fileformat)` from [doc/airline.txt](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline/blob/master/doc/airline.txt)
by inserting
`let g:airline_section_y = 'NOT_HERE'` into the .vimrc, but it gave me only this
[image]

`let g:airline_section_x = 'NOT_HERE'` X section - the same nothing
[image]

[image: Same with nerd tree]
There are no icons for file list at all. You can check my vimrc config [link](http://freetexthost.com/iplxmcqls4)

*XTerm*
[image]

- For the test, I even deployed vim in docker, latest ubuntu
- I disabled ALL plugins by PlugClean (vundle), and i still see this symbols
- Fonts: [powerline fonts](https://github.com/powerline/fonts)
- `:echo "\ue0b2"` Prints left arrow

**Please, tell me how can i remove them? Or what is this?**

Answer (score 3):

I think it's from the  Plug 'ryanoasis/vim-devicons' plugin. You probably need their specific patched fonts along with powerline fonts to work it. Because powerline fonts doesn't cover the huge list of fonts used in the awesome fonts.
Personally, I would be way away from these extra burdens just to get some icons in the terminal. So, please remove 'ryanoasis/vim-devicons' plugin and see if the problem goes away. If it does, then you can go ahead and find out how to work the plugin like the way you want to. Let me know what happened, Ok?

Comment: You are right! Thank you a lot!
I have commented this plugin, then :PlugClean, and symbols have disappeared.
Then, after re-entering vim, i've installed it again, just to be sure that problem in it, and symbols have appeared again.

Comment: Glad I could be of help. If you are satisfied with the answer, please, mark it as accepted.